# Material UI styled component - "The inferred type of X cannot be named without a reference..."

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, material-ui, styled-components

How is this TS issue resolved?
My styled component is exported from a `style.ts` file and used inside the `index.tsx` file of my React component:

style.ts:

```js
import { styled, Theme } from '@mui/material/styles';

type CardProps = {
    theme?: Theme;
    selected: boolean;
};

const Card = styled('div', {
    shouldForwardProp: (p) => !!p
})(({ theme, selected }: CardProps) => ({
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    padding: theme?.spacing(2),
    width: theme?.spacing(39.5),
    boxShadow: theme?.shadows[2],
    color: theme?.palette.grey[50],
    borderRadius: theme?.spacing(0.5),
    margin: `${theme?.spacing()} ${theme?.spacing(2)}`,
    ...(selected && {
        background: theme?.palette.grey[100],
        color: theme?.palette.getContrastText(theme?.palette.grey[100])
    }),
    ...(!selected && {
        cursor: 'pointer',
        border: `1px solid #DEE4EA`
    }),
    '&:hover': {
        ...(!selected && { color: theme?.palette.grey[100] })
    }
}));

export { Card }
```

index.tsx

```js
import { Card } from './style';

const ExperimentCard = ({
    id,
    selected,
    handleSelectCard,
}: Props) => (
 <Card data-cy="experiment-card" id={id} selected={selected} onClick={() => handleSelectCard(id)}>
    ...
</Card>
```

TS issue:

```
Plugin typescript: @rollup/plugin-typescript TS2742: The inferred type of 'Card' cannot be named without a reference to '@mui/material/node_modules/@mui/system'. This is likely not portable. A type annotation is necessary.
```

One suggestion I have found, was adding the suggested reference into the `tsconfig.json` file like below, but with no luck.

```json
"types": ["@mui/material/node_modules/@mui/system"],
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this issue using mui styled with pnpm in a monorepo setting. After some digging it seems to be caused by typescript not playing well with nested transitive dependencies.

Here are some relative issues on github where people discuss the root of the problem and pose some solutions:

[Typescript Issue #36800](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36800)

[Typescript Issue #30858](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30858)

I couldn't find a convenient solution that worked for pnpm, besides configuring `nodelinker=hoisted`, which defeats the purpose of using pnpm in the first place.

**EDIT**

It seems that installing `@mui/system` as a direct dependency worked, since `@mui/system` is now at the root level of `node_modules`. I had to reload my project window aswell to get typescript to play nice with vscode. This might cause problems however if the version you install as a direct dependency is incompatible with your version of `@mui/material`, so be careful if you take this approach.

In your case, it might be better to just map `@mui/system` directly to the nested dependency in your root level `tsconfig.json` file:

```json
"compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths:": {
        "@mui/system": "@mui/material/node_modules/@mui/system"
    }
}
```

Comment: Adding `@mui/system` in the path did not work, but installing `@mui/system` directly as a dev dependency did. Thank you so much @minnow!

Comment: I don't think this is a perfect solution. There might be the rare case where your project relies on two transitive dependencies of different versions. It's also a pain to make sure that the peer dependency you install is always the correct version.

I feel like there must be a better solution, I'm still not absolutely sure why this occurs but if there's some way to flatten peer dependencies with your package manager so there aren't any nested node_modules I would probably recommend that.

If I come across a better solution I will let you know

Comment: @GeorgeK's answer should be the solution to this problem, it really helps! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

This error usually indicates there are multiple versions of a dependency in the project, e.g. one defined in the package.json of a package, another specified as a dependency in root level package.json. You can verify this by running: `yarn why package-name`, e.g. `yarn why @mui/system`. In case of mismatching versions you'd see:

```
├─ my-repo@workspace:packages/react-components [c0f3f]
│  └─ @mui/system@npm:5.10.4 [9e221] (via npm:5.10.4 [9e221])
│
├─ my-repo@workspace:packages/react-components
│  └─ @mui/system@npm:5.10.4 [9e221] (via npm:5.10.4 [9e221])
│
├─ @mui/material@npm:5.10.4
│  └─ @mui/system@npm:5.11.16 (via npm:^5.10.4)
│
└─ @mui/material@npm:5.10.4 [9e221]
   └─ @mui/system@npm:5.11.16 [478da] (via npm:^5.10.4 [478da])
```

Notice how two first entries are using @mui/system 5.10.4, while the latter two use 5.11.16.

To fix it, update the mismatching version you defined in "dependencies" in your package.json to match the one required another library.

Here: `yarn workspace @my-repo/react-components add @mui/system@5.11.6`. Confirm whether it has taken effect by running `yarn info package-name` again.